# Hide progress bar for Android SDK sdkmanager cli command

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

When running the command `sdkmanager` to install or update the Android SDK using the command line interface, I always get a progress bar.

The problem is when running docker build the installation of the SDK takes over the logs with all the progress bar logged.

I'm using the this [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) command from the version `sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip`, and I am **not** setting the flag `--verbose`.

Is there any way to make the command run silent, without progress bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, `sdkmanager` doesn't have quite mode option. It is possible to suppress all standard output with `>/dev/null` though. For example,

```
RUN echo "y" | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3" \
    "emulator" \
    "platform-tools" \
    "platforms;android-28" \
    "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86_64" \
    "tools" >/dev/null
```

Comment: That's an option. But if something goes wrong with the installation I won't get errors back right? I'm just thinking that doing this in a CI setup might not be "safe", or would it?

Comment: Please, note that it suppresses `stdout` only while `stderr` output would still be printed and error code returned and handled. It is a common pattern in linux world you can search for the difference. I don't know if `sdkmanager` implemented printing errors correctly though.